# Можно сказать, что сайт О ЧЁМ-либо?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, управление

> И вот теперь я уже недовольно морщусь на нежный дождик по утрам, при
>   мартовской температуре + 18. Пока писала это, обнаружила, что я ведь
>   теперь почему-то старательно изучаю **сайты о погоде**. Хотя любой из
>   **прогнозов** здесь несёт в себе вероятность 50 на 50.

Нашла: сайты погоды, сайты прогноза погоды, сайты по прогнозу погоды,

но "прогноз" у меня уже есть...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Нашла: сайты погоды, сайты прогноза погоды, сайты по прогнозу погоды...

Как по мне, "сайт о погоде" звучит лучше всех перечисленных выше вариантов. Не знаю, что вызывает сомнения. Если обязательно нужно в гугле, тогда [вот](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=zmIpAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%22&dq=%22%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXzNvp2JfhAhVDwqYKHfNzBX0Q6AEIKDAA).

> Хотя любой из прогнозов здесь...

Не звучит ли это странно? Мне так и хочется сказать **для здесь** вместо **здесь** :)
Я понимаю выражение "прогноз (чего?) **погоды** (где?) в Москве", а "**прогноз** (где?) в Москве" понять не могу.

Comment: Ой, Гриззлик! "Здесь" - это где "я" лажу по сайтам.

Comment: Можно сказать: любой из здешних прогнозов.

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova Никогда бы не подумал :) Наверное потому, что я в таком случае сказал бы "там", а не "здесь" (я не утверждаю, что так правильно, просто поясняю недоумение).